# c++ Combining classes with temples - Declare other functions?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am having trouble understanding how to use templates with classes. I am sorry if this has been asked but I was unable to find an answer with Google. I have a header file that looks like this:

```
    /* 
 * File:   Jvec.h
 * Author: jspada20
 *
 * Created on July 29, 2014, 3:52 PM
 */

#ifndef JVEC_H
#define JVEC_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Jvec3
{
public:
    //jvec3();
    template<typename tt> Jvec3(tt px, tt py, tt pz) {
    x = px;
    y = py;
    z = pz;
    }

    template<typename tt> tt get_x(){
        return x;
    }

private:
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};
```

I am able to make the Jvec3 object without issue and am able to initialize it with out issue:

```
Jvec3<float> myVector(1.2,2.5,.69);
```

The issue I have is when I try to make a function that returns or changes the private variables. when I run the command:

```
cout << myVector.get_x();
```

I get the following output: main.cpp:21: main.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘Jvec3::get_x()’

Could someone clue me in on the correct syntax to pull this off?

Comment: You made your member functions templates for some reason. There are no arguments to `get_x()`, so template deduction cannot kick in. So you need to specify the template parameter: `myVector.get_x<FooBar>();`. This is of course quite a nonsensical interface.

Comment: Most sane thing to do is to remove inner templates `<typename tt>` from the member functions and change `tt` to `T`

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I have removed the inner template from the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* the desired behavior you're looking for is to remove the template declarations from inside your class definition. You only need to have the template declaration on your class, unless you want to define specialized template parameters for the member functions. If you haven't already, always good read up on syntax :) http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

```
template < typename T >
class Jvec3
{
    public:
    //jvec3();
    Jvec3(T px, T py, T pz)
    {
        x = px;
        y = py;
        z = pz;
    }
    T get_x()
    {
        return x;
    }
    private: 
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think what was messing me up was that I was using and example where the function existed outside of the class def. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the template parameter (there are cases where you dont have too, but here, the compiler cannot deduce it).

```
cout << myVector.get_x<float>();
                       ^^^^^
                        Here
```

---

However you design is ... strange, I guess that what you really want is to simply reuse the `T` template argument, you dont need template member functions at all :

```
template<typename T>
class Jvec3
{
public:
    Jvec3(T px, T py, T pz) {
       x = px;
       y = py;
       z = pz;
    }

    T get_x(){
        return x;
    }

private:
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};

int main(){
   Jvec3<float> myVector(1.2,2.5,.69);
   cout << myVector.get_x();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think what was messing me up was that I was using and example where the function existed outside of the class def. So if I have a template function I need to specify a type as I did with the class. It is not inferred from the values I am passing. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly (no problem)

Answer (score 0):

If you want use other class functions, you can just add it in `template<>`,then compiler can know that you need use other class.

```
template<typename T,class others>
class Jvec3
{
public:
    Jvec3(T px, T py, T pz) {
       x = px;
       y = py;
       z = pz;
    }

    T get_x(){
        return x;
    }

private:
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
    other* pother;
};
```